# Bluetooth malfunctioning with Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: bluetooth, 16.10

I installed Ubuntu 16.10 and from that moment I was never able to operate the bluetooth on my laptop. I specify that with the previous version of Ubuntu 16.04 installed on the same computer I never had problems with bluetooth. Moreover if I run the application Checkbox I get everything up and running. Nevertheless, there are times when the power indicator does not appear at all, and times when although the indicator appear, activating the function of adding new devices, it never interrupts without giving any message. I note that during startup of the operating system display shows the following **error message**:

```
Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout.
```

Can you help me? Thanks a lot

---

> **Computer Information:** - HP-15-Notebook - Memory: `3.3 GiB`; - Processor:  `AMD A8-6410 APU` with `AMD Radeon R5 Graphics × 4`; - Graphics: `Gallium 0.4` on `AMD MULLINS (DRM 2.46.0 / 4.8.0-26-generic, LLVM 3.8.1)`; - OS type: `64-bit`

---

Requested output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

```
ansfed@ansfed-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Harrier
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0000:0538  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23705351/